# How to create a link server: target is SQL server 2000 on a SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server

The target is a SQL server 2000 on remote host with firewall. Is it possible to create a link server on my local SQL server 2008 SSMS?

If yes, what should I pay attention to? And what ports should be open too? Thanks.

Comment: Both answers are good. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, you need to open up TCP port 1433 - However I'd strongly recommend using a VPN or at the very least restrict via the firewall the range of IPs allowed to connect.  Note that SQL traffic is unencrypted and **very** easy to read.

In management studio connect to the 2008 machine.  Then Server Objects->Linked Servers->Right click new Linked Server.

If you only want access to a couple of tables also checkout the Synonym functionality in books online.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the [MSDN documentation for "Creating Linked Servers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

- the port must be accessible through the firewall
- you create the instance using an account with appropriate permissions on the SQL Server 2000 box